# UIBarButtonItem from setTintColor back to its original color

Tags: objective-c, iphone, ios7, uibutton, tintcolor

I use setTintColor on a button and then I want to give it its original color back. As its bicolored, I can't re-use setTintColor.

```
[myBtn setTintColor:[UIColor pxColorWithHexValue:@"#888888"]];
```

How can I do ?

Thanks

Comment: "As its bicolored, I can't re-use setTintColor." What?

Comment: The button has two colors blue and green and I want them both to appear. Setting the tintColor to blue or to green is not a solution.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what you mean by not being able to re-use `setTintColor`. You should be able to just set `tintColor` back to `nil`, and it'll continue inheriting the color from further up the view hierarchy.